# OOXML want to use updated version of DocumentFormat.OpenXml dll version is 2.8.1.0

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

After updating DocumentFormat.OpenXml dll version to is 2.8.1.0.

I am getting the following error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried as follows, but getting the exception

`PM> Install-Package System.IO.Packaging`

Attempting to gather dependency information for package

> 'System.IO.Packaging.4.5.0' with respect to project 'xxx', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
>   Gathering dependency information took 1.93 ms
>   Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'System.IO.Packaging.4.5.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest
>   Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
>   Resolving actions to install package 'System.IO.Packaging.4.5.0'
>   Resolved actions to install package 'System.IO.Packaging.4.5.0'
>   Retrieving package 'System.IO.Packaging 4.5.0' from 'nuget.org'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Package 'System.IO.Packaging.4.5.0' does not exist in project 'xxx'
>   Package 'System.IO.Packaging.4.5.0' does not exist in folder 'E:\Working\Projects\xxx-OOXML-Aug22\packages
>   Executing nuget actions took 1.76 sec 
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.IO.Packaging 4.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a 
>   project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content 
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

**Note:** Our project .net version is 4.5.2
**Language:** c#

Comment: Have you tried removing your references, emptying your bin folder and then installing `Document.Format` and `System.IO` package from nuget?

Answer (score 0):

I have download OpenXML 2.8.1 and use it in a .net 4.5.2 project. It works for me without error.

According to you error message, did you use other dll? Did you use [System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives/)?

If you do not use OpenXML and just use the System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, will you get this error?